How can I create a mailing labels column in google sheets?
If I have Names, Addresses, Towns, States, and Zip Codes in a spread sheet. I want to create a new column in that spreadsheet with the information displayed in a mailing label like format.
so I would like the cell to input the data from the columns and add a few line breaks, a comma, and a few spaces.
e.g.
Name (insert a line break)
Address (insert a line break)
Town (insert a comma and a space) State (insert a space) Zip
I have been on google for an hour trying to locate an answer which I feel should be simple. Yet I either lack the correct language to describe my problem concisely or no one has done this before.
I am aware there are many label producing tools. But this is the one that will solve my particular problem.
Anyone got a formula that might work for me? (Thank you in advance for even reading my post)
Edit:
=(E3&" "&F3&" "&G3&", "&H3&" "&I3)
I have gotten this far, and it sort of works. But no line breaks. So basically my "mailing label" formatting is left up to the whims of the width of the column, instead of just doing it in the appropriate spot.
What I truly desire is just to drop in a "line break" symbol.
If ¶ worked as a line break I would desire this code...
=(E3&"¶"&F3&"¶"&G3&", "&H3&" "&I3)

Use E3&char(10)&F3 for a line break

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Try this:
=JOIN(CHAR(10),E3:G3)&", "&H3&" "&I3



This is Fantastic! Thanks so much. Works EXACTLY as I desired. I will now research JOIN and CHAR to see if I can understand the fish you have given me. TYVM

@AnthonyFry As a general rule in StackOverflow, if your concern is solved please accept an answer which works best for you by clicking the check mark beside the answer. This is to let other members from the community with the same concern as yours know that the issue is resolved. How to accept answer
